# How can I read offline receipt inpp purchase in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have implemented Inapp purchase in my app and validating receipt but I have problem with validate receipt when i am on offline.How can i do that?

Following is my code to validate when my interent is connected.

```
-(void)refreshRecipt
{
    NSError *error;
    _isUserActive = NO;

    NSURL *recieptUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle]appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSError *recieptError;

    BOOL isPresent = [recieptUrl checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&recieptError];

    if (!isPresent)
    {
        SKReceiptRefreshRequest *ref = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc]init];
        ref.delegate =self;
        [ref start];
        return;
    }

    NSData *reciptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:recieptUrl];
    if (!reciptData)
    {
        return;
    }

    dicPayload = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[reciptData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0] forKey:@"receipt-data"];

    [dicPayload setObject:@"21f843e264474b68b3a81c6b7ca19938" forKey:@"password"];

    NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dicPayload
                                                          options:0
                                                            error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:verifyRecieptURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                               if (connectionError) {
                                   NSLog(@"error");

                               } else {
                                   NSError *error;
                                   NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
                                           if ([jsonResponse objectForKey:@"latest_receipt_info"])
                                           {
                                               NSArray *array = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"latest_receipt_info"];
                                               NSLog(@"%@",array);

                                               NSDictionary *latestDetail = [array lastObject];
                                                if ([latestDetail objectForKey:@"is_trial_period"])
                                                {
                                                   if ([[latestDetail objectForKey:@"is_trial_period"] isEqualToString:@"true"])
                                                   {
                                                       _isFreeTrialActive  = YES;
                                                   }
                                                   else
                                                   {
                                                       _isFreeTrialActive = NO;
                                                   }

                                                   _isUserActive = [self calculateCurrentSubscriptionActive:[latestDetail objectForKey:@"expires_date_ms"]];


                                                   if (_isUserActive)
                                                   {
                                                       NSLog(@"User is active");
                                                       _SubscriptionActive = YES;

                                                   }
                                                   else
                                                   {
                                                       _SubscriptionActive = NO;
                                                       NSLog(@"User is not active");
                                                   }
                                                }
                                               else
                                               {
                                                   NSLog(@"no purachase done,first time user!");
                                               }
                                   }
                               }
                           }];

}
```

please help me to sort out this.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate you receipt locally, this is how you would do it according to apple documentation:

> Validate the Receipt
>
> To validate the receipt, perform the following tests, in order:
>
> 1- Locate the receipt.
>   If no receipt is present, validation fails.
>
> 2- Verify that the receipt is properly signed by Apple.
>   If it is not signed by Apple, validation fails.
>
> 3- Verify that the bundle identifier in the receipt matches a hard-coded constant containing the CFBundleIdentifier value you expect in the Info.plist file.
>   If they do not match, validation fails.
>
> 4- Verify that the version identifier string in the receipt matches a hard-coded constant containing the CFBundleShortVersionString value (for macOS) or the CFBundleVersion value (for iOS) that you expect in the Info.plist file.
>   If they do not match, validation fails.
>
> 5- Compute the hash of the GUID as described in Compute the Hash of the GUID.
>   If the result does not match the hash in the receipt, validation fails.
>
> If all of the tests pass, validation passes.

In order to do so you would first need to decrypt the receipt. For this you can use a library like [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore). Using this library you can do something like:

```
- (RMAppReceipt *)validReceipt {
    RMAppReceipt *receipt = [RMAppReceipt bundleReceipt];

    if (!receipt)
        //No receipt
        return nil;

    if (![receipt.bundleIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Your bundle ID"]) {
        //Receipt is invalid
        return nil;
    }
    if (![receipt verifyReceiptHash]) {
        //Receipt is invalid
        return nil;
    }

    //Receipt is valid
    return receipt;
}
```

`RMAppReceipt` contains all information from the receipt.

Comment: i don't use rmApp receipt. can you give me code without thirdparty

Comment: You should read this article: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html

Comment: Specifically this section: 
The outermost portion (labeled Receipt in the figure) is a PKCS #7 container, as defined by RFC 2315, with its payload encoded using ASN.1 (Abstract Syntax Notation One), as defined by ITU-T X.690. The payload is composed of a set of receipt attributes. Each receipt attribute contains a type, a version, and a value.

Comment: The structure of the payload is defined using ASN.1 notation in Listing 1-1. You can use this definition with the asn1c tool to generate data type declarations and functions for decoding the payload, rather than writing that part of your code by hand. You may need to install asn1c first; it is available through MacPorts and SourceForge.

Comment: If you don't want to deal with this, you should look into using a third party library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146594/discussion-between-l-l-and-maulik).